# How can I pass props to route components in vue.js using Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm still new to learning vue.js. I'm trying to introduce a dropdown menu into my website so I can simply navigate to other pages. The problem is when I try and pass props in the manner that the documentation shows I keep getting undefined.

I have my vue-router setup properly as you can see below but in an effort to keep my components re-usable I would like to be able to pass props to my from my parent element to the child element. For clarity I followed the tutorial on this [link](https://medium.com/@ronnow/dropdowns-in-vue-the-right-way-8ff9e8f36d4a) and was able to get it successfully implemented. The main link I've been working and testing on is the "cooling" link, shown below.

**src/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('../views/index.vue'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/our-story',
    name: 'OurStory',
    component: () => import('../views/our-story.vue'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/services/:slug', ///cooling
    name: '/cooling', //Cooling
    component: () => import('../views/cooling.vue'),
    //props: true
    props: true
    //props: path => ({ link: () => import('../views/cooling.vue')})
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

**appDropdown.vue**

```
<!--Contain the whole dropdown component-->
<script>
    import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';

    export default {
        name: 'AppDropdown',
        mixins: [ clickaway ],
        /*props: {
            path: { type: String, required: true }
        },*/
        //props: [ 'path' ],
        props: {
            slug: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        provide () {
            return {
                sharedState: this.sharedState,
                //path: this.path
                slug: this.slug
            }
        }, 
        data () {
            return {
                sharedState: {
                    active: false
                },
                //slug: this.$route.params.slug
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle () {
                this.sharedState.active = !this.sharedState.active
            },
            away () {
                this.sharedState.active = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div @click="toggle" v-on-clickaway="away">
        <slot name="toggler">
            <button>Toggle</button>
        </slot>
        <slot/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I attempted to pass the props as "slug" for my link and then shared this into the Provide method to push it down to the child component. Here is where I run into issues as the console throws an error stating that "Missing required prop: slug".

**appDropdownContent.vue**

```
<!--Wrap the menu component-->
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'AppDropdownContent',
        inject: ['sharedState', 'slug'],
        computed: {
            active () {
                return this.sharedState.active
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div v-if="active">
        <slot/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I've then injected the "slug" here although I think it may need to go down further to the next code segment which encloses the ""

**appDropdownItem.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'AppDropdownItem'
    }
</script>

<template>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <slot/>
    </a>
    <!--<a :href="$route.component" class="">
        <slot/>
    </a>-->
</template>
```

I know this may be overkill for what I need so I am open to other options on how to accomplish this in a workable fashion. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `provide` and `inject` is not a way to pass props so the error in the console log is expected. You can simply pass your props like [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details). I recommend you read all the Vue official documents. It will help you have a whole picture in mind

Comment: @duannx thank you for helping to point me in the right direction. After doing some more reading am I correct in assuming that I'm getting the error because the prop has not been added to the template syntax? {{ slug }}

Comment: What error are you referring to? If you don't include your props in the template, it will not throw an error at all. You use {{slug}} when you want to show your slug in your final HTML. Again, you don't need to use provide, inject here. Honestly, I don't know your exact issue but I think you are missing some fundamental knowledge. There are some [free tutorials](https://vueschool.io/courses/vue-js-fundamentals-with-the-composition-api) out there. I recommend you take one to start